# Can I add a MouseMotionListener to another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouseevent

I have one very busy thread trying to do everything, and it's starting to slow down my MouseMotionListener.  I thought I would put the listener in another thread to make sure it's always running as quickly as it can, but as soon as I made it:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class MouseListenerThread extends Thread implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void run(){
        //Concurrency happens here  
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do something 
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

I realized that while I could have this other object function as a mouse listener, I couldn't do it concurrently.  Is there any way I can use the run function to achieve listening?  I would also accept any other solution for speeding up the listener.

Thanks!

Comment: In Swing you shouldn't be doing anything long-running in the event dispatch thread. Your very busy thread should be some other thread that you create. Your mouse listener will be called from the event dispatch thread and so the two threads should not be interfering with one another.

Comment: If you have a process that is impacting the `EDT`, consider placing that functionality in a `SwingWorker`. `MouseListeners` should only be found in the `EDT`,

Comment: So you're saying to just switch the two classes, and have all the business go to the alternate thread, and keep all the mouse listening where it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual listener that receives the `mouseDragged` etc has to be on the event dispatch thread (EDT). Any "non GUI" work being done in those event handling methods, could be farmed off to other threads using `SwingWorker`or any other threading methods.

All GUI work must be in the event dispatch thread, so if the event handlers are slowing down because of GUI stuff you might be in trouble, but you can use `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` to trigger any thread to schedule some work for the EDT thread. You can also use `InvokeAndWait`, but that is starting got couple your GUI quite tightly to the backed...

Comment: Haha, it kind of is.  Well a lot of intensive stuff with big for loops could easily be placed somewhere else, so when this thing is doing almost nothing but drawing and mouse listening, that's as much as I can expect, right?

Comment: `All GUI work must be in the main thread` --> the main thread is not the same as the GUI-thread (EDT).

Comment: @John3136 I'm still confused about your reference to `InvokeLater`.  If you mean `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater()` the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) pretty clearly indicates the `Runnable` passed into this will execute on the EDT.

Comment: @JasonBraucht Very good point. I've edited the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

All events are dispatched by the Event Dispatching Thread. Placing your mouse listener in another Thread will make absolutely no difference, as the event methods will be notified within the context of the EDT

Swing is a single threaded framework. This means that all interactions with UI must be executed from within the EDT context. So even if you could off load the work to another thread, you would need to resync any changes/updates to the UI with the EDT.

You might like to take read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details.

If you are executing long running/blocking tasks within the EDT, yu may wish to consider using a `SwingWorker`, which will allow you run tasks in a separate thread, but provides methods for simplifying the process of updating the UI